# JQuery Error -- Slowing Down Actions to View Error in Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see my script is running into an error when I click onto the image on my page [here](http://dev.autopartsnetwork.com/performance-auto-repair-parts/air-filters/air-filter/mann-filter-air-filter-469398.html). It's supposed to be a lightbox but I can't even see the Javascript error before it reloads.

Please help me understand how I can slow down the execution so that I may troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

Comment: I saw the comment once I finished submitting my answer. Please take time to read that article.

Comment: after clicking on the image console shows `TypeError: Cannot call method 'lastIndexOf' of undefined`

Comment: @BrianSchroeter - if my answer solved your problem, could you accept it please? If not, at least leave a comment so that I can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Chrome as a browser, follow these steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to open the Developer Tools.
2. Got to the Sources tab.
3. In the bottom bar, you will see an octagonal button with two vertical lines. This button has three possible states indicated by color:

   1. Inactive (Gray) - this is the default state in which your script will execute normally.
   2. Pause on all exception (Blue) - this will stop the execution of JS as soon as any exception is encountered.
   3. Pause on uncaught exception (Purple) - this will only stop the execution if an exception has been thrown which is not going to be caught in any catch block. This is what you generally want since you want to see the cases which you didn't handle in the code.

Once the script execution has paused, you can move up and down the stack trace to figure out what went wrong.

And of course, follow the advice from @FelixKling.